# Не могу спарсить таблицу с сайта - Can't parsing table from site -

Tags: python, парсер

https://raex-rr.com/ESG/ESG_companies/ESG_rating_companies/2023.5/

need to parsing table from website
get error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

code:

```
url = 'https://raex-rr.com/ESG/ESG_companies/ESG_rating_companies/2023.5/'
page = requests.get(url)

print(page.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
soup

table1 = soup.find('table', id='rrp_table_wrapper')
table1

# Obtain every title of columns with tag <th>
headers = []
for i in table1.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text
    headers.append(title)
```

Comment: Вопросы нужно задавать по-русски. особенно, если с английским у вас не очень.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from requests_toolbelt.sessions import BaseUrlSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import pandas as pd

s = BaseUrlSession('https://raex-rr.com')
response = s.get('ESG/ESG_companies/ESG_rating_companies/2023.5')

soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')
df, = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('#rrp_table_wrapper')))
```

| № | Название | Код MOEX | Подотрасль | ESG Rank | ESG-рейтинг | E Rank | E-рейтинг | S Rank | S-рейтинг | G Rank | G-рейтинг | Год последней оцененной отчетности |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | НЛМК | NLMK | Чёрная металлургия | 1 | AA | 2 | AA | 2 | AA | 21 | A | 2021 |
| 2 | «Полюс» | PLZL | Драгоценные металлы | 2 | AA | 1 | AAA | 14 | A | 27 | A | 2021 |
| 3 | «Уралкалий» | — | Агрохимикаты | 3 | A | 6 | BBB | 1 | AA | 6 | AA | 2021 |
| 4 | «Энел Россия» | ENRU | Электроэнергетика | 4 | A | 9 | BBB | 9 | A | 2 | AAA | 2021 |

Comment: Красиво, без set.options ответ выглядит по другому, но плюсанул.

Comment: @Oopss и в каком месте здесь должно быть, по Вашему мнению, упомянутое Вами `set.options`

Comment: Я хочу сказать, что данный код не соответствует  выводу,  код ничего не выводит.

Comment: @Oopss, я где-то написал что ниже представлен вывод?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что BS4 не находит таблицу и соответственно дальше не может выполнять методы поиска.

```
soup.find('table')
```

Ищет элемент с тэгом `table`, вы же указываете id элемента, являющегося `div`, внутри указанного вами дива находится необходимая таблица.
Поэтому вам достаточно поменять строку:

```py
table1 = soup.find('table', id='rrp_table_wrapper')
```

на:

```py
table1 = soup.find('table', class_='rrp_table')
```